# Appending to the dataset in neo4j

Tags: database, import, neo4j, graph-databases

I have used the neo4j import tool to do a bulk import of about 45k nodes and 40k relationships.Now data can always be added to my database and the size will be ever expanding.Is there a way to append the new data(which will also be very large) to the existing database using import tool...?
Note: I have tried using LOAD CSV and it is very slow because of the size of my data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it bypasses transactions and writes directly to the filestore, the `neo4j-import` tool is only used for initial data import.

For incremental bulk updates `LOAD CSV` is an option for loading from CSV. You can also combine operations in a single transaction to increase throughput of writes. Typically it is safe to run 10k-50k database operations per transaction.

You say `LOAD CSV` is too slow. How many rows in the CSV file? Are you using indexes for any lookups? Can you share the `LOAD CSV` statements?

Comment: The csv commands I'm using include:                                                              LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///node_person_l.csv" AS csvLine 
MERGE (u:User { email: csvLine.email}),u.name = csvLine.name;  and the csv file has 5000 nodes and this is taking almost a minute to complete..Also do you have any suggestion for creating relationships between various nodes written across different csv files??

Comment: Do you have an index on User(email)?

Comment: no..i want to create indices for the user nodes as a property like every node will have a property user_id which i will manually assign..

Comment: You should create a uniqueness constraint on User(email): `CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (u:User) ASSERT u.email IS UNIQUE;` This will 1) ensure there are no duplicate user email values and 2) create an index to increate performance. See [the docs](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/#query-merge) for more info

Comment: Thanks a lot ..William Lyon